# Thread Safety with Paralel.For

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application that runs on a machine with multiple processors.  When I run the code in visual studio on my development machine it runs fairly quickly.  When I run the published version on the server with the same inputs, it runs more slowly.  I'm working on a theory, here.  My development laptop has a single processor with a higher clock speed than the multiple processors on the server.  Since the application is single-threaded, it seems logical that it would run faster locally.  So, if I can add some multithreading to the application to make use of the additional processors on the server, I might be able to improve performance.  That's the theory, anyway.  And my experience with multithreaded applications is limited.

The crux of the application is a loop which calls several methods.  A simplified version would look something like:

```
public DataTable MyMethod()
{
    DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();
    <add columns to the data table>

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= MaxCounter; counter++)
    {
        <<generate some values>>

        ComputeOutputsByRecipe(id, ref MyDataTable);
    }

    return MyDataTable;
}

private void ComputeOutputsByRecipe(int RecipeID, ref DataTable Results)
{
    switch (RecipeID)
    {
        case 1:
           ProcessRecipe_1(ref Results);
           break;

        case 2:
           <repeat for supported recipe IDs>
    }
}

private void ProcessRecipe_1(ref DataTable Results)
{
    <do some processing>

    DataRow dr = Results.NewRow();
    <populate the new data row>
    Results.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

So what I'm looking to do is replace the "For" with "Paralel.For" to take advantage of multiple threads running on multiple processors.  But since each iteration of the loop writes to a reference parameter, I'm concerned about thread safety.  Now... the order that the data gets written to this data table is not important.  And I don't read from the data table until after the looping has completed.  So I don't think that this is a problem.  But since `Add()` is an instance method, I'm concerned about what would happen.

So the question is, is it safe to add rows to a datatable like this if the for loop in my example is replaced with Paralel.For() and I don't read from the data table until after the loop has completed?

Comment: I'm guessing that the resource intensive bit is your `ProcessRecipe_1` method? You could utilise a `Parallel.For()` and invoke a delegate on your main thread for each loop to actually add the row to your table.

Comment: Note that there's not reason to pass the `DataTable` using `ref`.  You never mutate the variable, only its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not safe.  `DataTable` is not designed to be mutated from multiple concurrent threads.

You'll need to synchronize access to it in order to ensure it works properly.

Comment: So I would need to lock the data table before performing the `Add()` right?

Comment: @DeadZone You would way to synchronize *all* access to it.